# Am i doing wrong for script to work many times?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i tried to run this script using either while loop and  with for loop both doesnt work.

i mean it stop working after 1 repetition.

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("submit").click()
x = driver.find_element_by_class_name("submit").click()
for x in range(100):
 time.sleep(0.1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Continue >>']").click()
time.sleep(2.5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(.,'Restart Battle')]").click()
print(x)
```

i have posted the important part of the code which i think need to be revised but i am not sure where i am making mistake.

i have posted below images of my full script for further clarifications

https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2Yyr.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1OxT.jpg

Comment: i tried to post whole script but it was giving me error saying that post contains everything in codes needed to add details

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_indentation.asp#

Comment: I don't understand the `for x in range(100): time.sleep(0.1)`. What is the point of that? Why not just say `time.sleep(10)`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that Python has no idea what you want to loop. In Python spacing is very important. You need to add tabs in from of the code that you want to loop or else Python is just going to skip it.
For example, this is not going to work:

```
for x in "banana":
print(x)
```

But this is going to work because it has a tabulator in front:

```
for x in "banana":
  print(x)
```

I took this simple example from [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp)

Comment: i have tried this but it doesnt work as well

Comment: Do you get any error messages or does it just not run the code?

Comment: thanks it worked i was making mistake by not writing the whole code by giving it to spaces

Comment: That's what I tried to say haha. Sorry for my bad explanation

Answer (score 0):

Use the While loop with the condition to check if the continue button or attack button exist. once both of them don't exist it will come out of the loop. Till that it will keep clicking